# How can I loop through a range of cells and get a value to them from a website?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Im trying to get some specific data from a website my workplace uses, however, I cannot figure out on how to get some specific data to be written to a worksheet. I have written a code, which successfully opens the webpage and loops through the data on that page, I just need help with the last part of the code.

```
Dim Source As Range
        Dim Cell As Range

lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
Set Source = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

For Each Cell In Source


Dim nodes As Object, i2 As Long

Set nodes = objIE.Document.querySelectorAll("[Title='Purchase Order / Status']")

For i2 = 0 To nodes.Length - 1

    If nodes.Item(i2).innerText Like "*" & Cell.Value & "*" Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ' Im missing the code here
        Exit For
    End If

Next
Next
```

Im missing the last part of the code (marked in the above code as missing). This code loops through my worksheet, then the whole webpage, and looks for the data titled 'Purchase Order / Status'. This part of the code is fine.

Then I tried `Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = objIE.Document.querySelector("[Title='Planned Destinations ']").innerText`, which successfully gets the 'Planned Destinations' innertext value, which I need. However, it just always gets the first found 'Planned Destinations' innertext on the whole page.

Here is a picture of what it does and what I want it to do:

[image: Example]

Notice the D column.

Here is a piece of the website:

```
<tr class="outboundPlanAltRowStyle">
<td class="outboundPlanHour" style="height:25px;width:40px;white-space:nowrap;">11:00</td>
 <td onmouseover="this.className='outboundPlanHover'" onmouseout="this.className=''" 
     onclick="cellClicked(1019543,14)" 
     style="height:25px;width:150px;white-space:nowrap;" class="">
<table class="outboundPlan_PREBOOKED" style="width: 200px; table-layout: fixed" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
   <tbody><tr>
    <td title="Purchase Order / Status" class="outboundCell"> 325839 / PREBOOKED</td></tr>
    <tr><td title="Subcontractor Name / Load Numbers " 
               class="outboundCell">Tesco FM /  - </td></tr>
    <tr><td title="Planned Destinations " class="outboundCell" 
       style="overflow: hidden"> 39019 (NDC Teresin)&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td title="Status Date" class="outboundCell">28.01.2021 12:02&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody>
</table></td>
```

I need the title="Planned Destinations " innertext value to the cells by finding title="Purchase Order / Status" innertext, which is saved in the worksheet (Column A in the picture above)

**EDIT:**

Finally managed to make it to work. Used a different approach to my problem, but without the hints and helps of Tim I wouldnt be able to finish it. Heres the final, working code to my problem, in case anyone needs it, or an inspiration:

```
Dim objResultList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
        Dim lResultCount As Long
        Dim lResultLoop As Long
        Dim anchorLoop As MSHTML.HTMLAnchorElement

Set objResultList = objIE.Document.querySelectorAll("[Title='Planned Destinations ']")
    
    lResultCount = objResultList.Length

    Debug.Print
    
    For lResultLoop = 0 To lResultCount - 1
        
        Set anchorLoop = objResultList.Item(lResultLoop)
     
    Next
        
    i3 = 0
    Set Source = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & lastRow)
    If Not anchorLoop Is Nothing Then
    For Each Cell In Source
    Cell.Value = objResultList.Item(i3).innerText
    i3 = i3 + 1
    
    Next
    End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go "up" from `nodes.Item(i2)` to the parent table  (using e.g. `parentElement`), then query that table (not the whole document) for the other cell you want:

```vba
Sub tester()
    'Added reference to Microsoft HTML Object Model
    Dim doc As New HTMLDocument, nodes As Object, i As Long
    Dim tbl As HTMLTable, nxt
    
    doc.body.innerHTML = Range("A1").Value 'load HTML from cell for testing

    Set nodes = doc.querySelectorAll("td [Title='Purchase Order / Status']")
    Debug.Print "found " & nodes.Length & " cell(s)"
    
    For i = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
    
        'get the parent table
        Set tbl = nodes(i).parentElement.parentElement.parentElement
        'find the other cell in this table
        Set nxt = tbl.querySelector("td [Title='Planned Destinations ']")
        
        Debug.Print nodes(i).innerText, nxt.innerText
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

HTML in A1:

```html
<table><tr>
      <td>11:00</td>
     <td>
             <table class="outboundPlan_PREBOOKED">
            <tbody>
                    <tr><td title="Purchase Order / Status" class="outboundCell"> 325839 / PREBOOKED</td></tr>
                   <tr><td title="Subcontractor Name / Load Numbers "  class="outboundCell">Tesco FM /  - </td></tr>
                   <tr><td title="Planned Destinations " class="outboundCell" >39019 (NDC Teresin)&nbsp;</td></tr>
                   <tr><td title="Status Date" class="outboundCell">28.01.2021 12:02&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            </table></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: It gives me an "Object required" error and highlights the `Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = node.parentElement.querySelector("[Title='Planned Destinations ']").innerText` line.

Comment: Sorry I don't have access to the page to debug that.  Hopefully it gave you a starting point though.

Comment: I've managed to make it work by putting a second parentElement into the line, like this: `Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Node.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("[Title='Planned Destinations ']").innerText` Now it gets the first 'Planned Destinations ' innertext, and after that an error occurs: `Run-time error 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable` . Any advice on fixing this ?

Comment: I missed that the cells are on different rows, so you have to go "up" to the table level and down from there.

Comment: When I try to apply it to the webpage, it gives `Method 'item' of object 'DispstaticNodeList' failed` error and highlights the `Set tbl = nodes(i).parentElement.parentElement.parentElement` line. All i did was change the `Set nodes = doc.querySelectorAll("td [Title='Purchase Order / Status']")` to `Set nodes = objIE.Document.querySelectorAll("[Title='Purchase Order / Status']")` to reference the website. Also, where is the `oNode As HTMLTableCell` used in the code ? It seems like its an array collection, but `For Each` cannot be used to loop through them. Any other method ?

Comment: `oNode` was left over from a different edit - I've removed it.  All I can say is that worked for me in my testing, but obviously I'm not using the same environment you are.  I'm using HTMLDocmuent and not IE, and I don't have access to the complete page.

Comment: Finally managed to make it work, however, I used a slightly different approach to it.